# DropDownList to populate from MySQL db using specific filter

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, dropdown

I am trying to populate a DropDownList from `MySQL` db. It's working fine, however I am trying to apply one filter there.
The program I am developing is a `POS` software so the DropDownList should only populate from `MySQL` if the inventory has more than `0` items available for sale.

Clicking on a "+" button populates the DropDownList from `MySQL` db.

Here's the code for that button:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=chanamotors")
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `itemname`, `itemcode`, `saleprice`, `quantity` FROM inventory", connection)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)

    BunifuDropdown1.DataSource = table
    BunifuDropdown1.ValueMember = "itemname"
    BunifuDropdown1.DisplayMember = "itemname"
End Sub
```

Now I am trying to add a filer like if `quantity = 0` then the item name won't be displayed on the dropdown list.

Comment: Seems pretty trivial.... `SELECT \`itemname\`, \`itemcode\`, \`saleprice\`, \`quantity\` FROM inventory WHERE quantity > 0` unless I've missed something in my understanding? BTW never get your applications to log in as "root", even for testing, it gives them far too much privilege. Instead create an account in SQL specifically for the application, with only the permissions it actually needs

Comment: thanks, my bad I am weak in mysql commands. thank you so much

Comment: Understood about the root part as well. Noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily in the SQL command by adding a WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT `itemname`, `itemcode`, `saleprice`, `quantity` FROM inventory WHERE quantity > 0
```